# How to pass the data provider data when page factory method is applied

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, eclipse, page-factory

I have created a sample project using the page factory. Now I want to use the data provider in the code and this is how I have done below. Is the approach correct?
I have defined CommonElements class to initialise the WebElements:

```
    public class CommonElements {
        public static WebElement element;

        WebDriver driver;
        @FindBy(name="firstname")
        public WebElement firstname;
        @FindBy(name="lastname")
        public WebElement lastname;
        @FindBy(name="sex")
        public WebElement gender;
        @FindBy(name="exp")
        public WebElement experience;
        @FindBy(id="datepicker")
        public WebElement date1;
        @FindBy(name="profession")
        public WebElement prof;
        @FindBy(name="tool")
        public WebElement tool;
        @FindBy(id="continents")
        public WebElement contain;
        @FindBy(id="selenium_commands")
        WebElement selcom;
        @FindBy(id="submit")
        WebElement submit;      

        public CommonElements(WebDriver driver) {
           this.driver=driver;
           PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        }

        @DataProvider(name="first")
        public static Object[][] dataProviderMethod() {
            return new Object[][] { {"rutvi"}};
        }

        @Test(dataProvider="first")
        public void setfirstname(String fname) {
           firstname.clear();
           firstname.sendKeys(fname);
        }

        public void setlastname(String lname) {
           lastname.clear();
           lastname.sendKeys(lname);
        }
   }
```

And defined another class which contains all the tests.

```
public class Validdata {
    Setup s1=new Setup();

    @Test
    public void valid() throws InterruptedException {
        CommonElements c1=new CommonElements(s1.driver);
        String s=c1.firstname.toString();
        System.out.println("s->"+s);

        c1.setfirstname("s");
        c1.setlastname("Soni");
    }
}
```

Comment: Really could not understand your design considerations. Your question is also not clear. However if you want to make use of a data provider of one class in another, just add another attribute 'dataProviderClass=className.class' in the @Test annotation and make the data provider method as static. http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#parameters-dataproviders -- documentation for reference.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood your question correctly, then following are the changes that you need to do: 
1. The method `setfirstname` is not a Test method, so remove the @Test annotation.
 
2. The method `valid` under the `Validdata` class is a Test method so add the annotation `@Test(dataProvider="first", dataProviderClass=CommonElements.class)`

So your test method looks like this:

```
    @Test(dataProvider="first", dataProviderClass=CommonElements.class)
    public void valid(String fname) throws InterruptedException {
        CommonElements c1=new CommonElements(s1.driver);
        c1.setfirstname(fname);
        c1.setlastname("Soni");
    }
```

Your `firstname` is set as `rutvi` and `lastname` to `Soni` on your web browser.

On a side note, the below statement doesn't make sense.

```
String s=c1.firstname.toString();
```

Here, you are trying to convert `firstname` (which is a WebElement) to String. It wouldn't give you any meaningful name.

Comment: If we have to pass the multiple parameter in the data provider then we can not pass if we call data provider above the valid method.

Comment: Agree, but for that you can use different test data for multiple parameter.

Comment: Ya but we can pass multiple data in the data provider but how we can call that methodpublic void valid() throws InterruptedException {
        CommonElements c1=new CommonElements(s1.driver);
     
        c1.setfirstname("s");
        c1.setlastname("Soni");
    }
if we are create object and call the method through the object then how can we pass the parameter through data provider

Comment: You don't have to create object and invoke the `valid()` method explicitly, it is invoked by the test framework. Since you have specified the `dataProvider` for the test (with @Test annotation), the method `dataProviderMethod() ` provides data to the test method `valid()`.